# AG-GRID close mini filter popup by clicking on show icon again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid community. And I am using the ag-grid mini filter popup, which works really well. But I would like to overwrite one default behavior and I found it difficult.
So I have my own cell renderer and by clicking on bars icon I show columnMenu with applied event listener onMenuClick:

```
CustomColumnHeader.prototype.onMenuClick = function () {
  this.agParams.showColumnMenu(this.eMenuButton)
}
```

But I would like to close mini filter popup when it's open and I click on bars icon again. I tried to add a variable in my init field, that determine if the popup is open, but... I can't watch when the popup is closed by e.g. ESC key press. I didn't find any event or method in ag-grid that can help me.
Anyone with an idea of how to solve it?

Regards